# Invalid prop `component` of type `object` supplied to `Route`, expected `function`

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-redux

I've been struggling with this for awhile and can't seem to find anyone else with the same issue. I've got this component and container which are my start screen which should be rendered at the initial route.

**components/DifficultySelection.jsx**

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

export default class DifficultySelection extends React.Component{

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.onClick = this.onClick.bind(this);
  }

  onClick(e){
    this.props.onDifficultyClick(e.target.innerHTML);

    this.props.history.push("/play");
  }

  render(){
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>Select your difficulty</h2>
        <div>
          <h3 onClick={this.onClick}>Easy</h3>
          <h3 onClick={this.onClick}>Medium</h3>
          <h3 onClick={this.onClick}>Hard</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

DifficultySelection.propTypes = {
  onDifficultyClick: PropTypes.func.isRequired
}
```

**containers/DifficultySelection.jsx**

```
import DifficultySelection from '../components/DifficultySelection';
import { setBoardSize } from '../actions/actions';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch, ownProps) => {
  return {
  onDifficultyClick: (difficulty) => {
      console.log(difficulty);
      let boardSize = 8;
      if(difficulty === "Medium")  boardSize = 12;
      if(difficulty === "Hard") boardSize = 15;
      if(difficulty === "Extreme") boardSize = 20;

      dispatch(setBoardSize(boardSize));
    }
  }
}

export default withRouter(connect(
  null,
  mapDispatchToProps
))(DifficultySelection)
```

Below is where I try and assign these components to a route. This is where I am getting the error. As an aside, the console logs I put in show that the components I'm importing are `Route` functions, the image of which is included because it should be a class I think.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';
import reducers from './reducers/reducers';
import { createStore, combineReducers } from 'redux';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { HashRouter, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';

import DifficultySelection from './containers/DifficultySelection';
import Board from './containers/Board';

let store = createStore(combineReducers(reducers));

console.log(DifficultySelection.type);
console.log(Board.type);

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <HashRouter>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={DifficultySelection}/>
        <Route exact path="/play" component={Board}/>
      </Switch>
    </HashRouter>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root'));
registerServiceWorker();
```

[image]

Comment: Or just `connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(DifficultySelection)`, since you'll already get the router props directly from `Route`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue is with:

```
export default withRouter(connect(
  null,
  mapDispatchToProps
))(DifficultySelection)
```

The syntax for `connect` is `connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(component)`

Putting your call on a single line, it's perhaps easier to see the error:

`withRouter(connect(null, mapDispatchToProps))(DifficultySelection)`

`connect` never properly uses `DifficultySelection` as an arugment, meaning your file is not returning the connected component.

Simply rearrange it as follows:

```
export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(withRouter(DifficultySelection))
```

Or, as suggested in the comments, `withRouter` can be omitted since this component will receive props from `Route`:

```
export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(DifficultySelection)
```